# an open source project that uses logging in the extreme

Tags: java, ruby, logging

There are many toy examples of logging.  I am looking for a large example,
that is real world production code, and make extreme use of logging.

thank you

Comment: What is extreme use of logging, and why?  Logs slow down your application. I think, for example, adding a log on every other line of code would be "extreme", but not so smart.

Comment: @bwawok: modern logging frameworks dodge the *"pay the logging price even if you don't log"* by only evaluating the parameters/constructing all the Strings if the log level is matching.  So I'm pretty sure the OP could find a project using such a logging framework that has countless *log.debug* and *log.info* and yet hardly pay any price at all if the level is set to *log.warn* no!?

Comment: There is still cost to going in a log method and returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about *extreme*, but have a look at [OpenESB](https://open-esb.dev.java.net/).  It is built on top of [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/).  It uses a very flexible approach to logging that is easily user configurable (it is a product targeted at developers after all).

As a user, you have the ability to select the logging level for various parts of the system (which includes plugins, hence my recommendation of OpenESB) to see how it behaves.

Answer (score 1):

Nagios comes to mind. It is a monitoring application which monitors logifles, diskspace, sockets, .... We are a medium sized company and do a couple million checks per day. There are much larger deployments.

We end up with billions of loglines which need to be pruned. And that is a pity.

It is not an extreme example, but it's real and could do with some distributed map-reduce love.